# R For loop, multivariate and multidimensional

Tags: r

I am trying to create a `for` loop that runs a linear regression for each row of my data and graphs each line on a single graph. I have 134 rows, each row is a country, and 64 independent variables (`X2` to `X65`), with `X1` as my dependent variable. There are also some missing values which are `NA`. I feel like I should convert my data into a multidimensional array but I am struggling with how to convert my data properly, it is currently a data frame called `reg.data`.

This where I am currently:

```
results <- list()
for (i in 1:nrow(reg.data)){
       r1 <- lm(reg.data[,i] ~ ., data=reg.data)
       results[[i]] <- summary(r1)
}
plot(results)
```

Below is the `dput(head(reg.data,1))`:

```
structure(list(`Country Number` = 1, code = "DZA", country = "Algeria", 
gamma = "0.0136902", X1 = 7.43897151947021, X2 = 47.2999992370605, 
X3 = 0.46000000834465, X4 = 0, X5 = 0, X6 = 0.130999997258186, 
X7 = 186.555465698242, X8 = 21.0690002441406, X9 = 13.3030004501343, 
X10 = 8.0649995803833, X11 = 10.1800003051758, X12 = 1, X13 = 2382, 
X14 = 0.218471005558968, X15 = 0.0270869992673397, X16 = 
0.0284170787781477, 
X17 = 0.736000001430511, X18 = 0.101999998092651, X19 = 
0.0130000002682209, 
X20 = 0.850000023841858, X21 = 0.0799999982118607, X22 = 
0.00300000002607703, 
X23 = 0, X24 = 0.230100005865097, X25 = 0.0590999983251095, 
X26 = 0.0296999998390675, X27 = 0.0299999993294477, X28 = 0, 
X29 = 0.123000003397465, X30 = 0.166500002145767, X31 = 0, 
X32 = 5.83333301544189, X33 = 5.88888883590698, X34 = 36.7200012207031, 
X36 = 0.430000007152557, X37 = 0.272000014781952, X38 = 0.933000028133392, 
X39 = 0.333333343267441, X40 = 0.303999990224838, X41 = 190, 
X42 = 0.0507000014185905, X43 = 0.190699994564056, X44 = 6.3231258392334, 
X45 = -0.012636000290513, X46 = -1.33029210567474, X47 = NA_real_, 
X48 = 0, X49 = 1, X50 = 0, X51 = 0, X52 = 0, X53 = 0, X54 = 0, 
X55 = 0.00499999988824129, X56 = 0.990000009536743, X57 = 
0.00499999988824129, 
X58 = 2855.52001953125, X59 = 0.195999994874001, X60 = 0, 
X61 = 0.836000025272369, X62 = 0), row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: You to perform the linear regression with the entire dataset.  It does make sense trying to estimate all of the coefficients with one line of data.  Next, you will need to fix the NA in the data. Either drop those columns with NA or remove those rows.

Comment: nesting your dataset sounds like an option, but can you show a reproducible dataset? See `dput` to do so.

Comment: @Ali I have edited in the dput so you can see what I am working with.

Comment: @Dave2e any suggestions about how I could do that with a for loop?

Comment: you cannot run a regression for every row.. how can u regress with 1 observation?

Comment: You don't need a for loop.  You want to perform the regression on the entire dataset just 1 time.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned you only need to run the linear regression once. The minimum number of observations required is 2 to run a regression.

In your case, the number of independent variables are: p = 64 (X2 to X65) + 2 (country and gamma) = 66.

If 'code' is unique for every country then you will want to leave this out because of collinearity between country and code.

The number of observations you have is the number of rows, n = 134.

Therefore, the only line you need to run is:

```
lm(X1 ~  X2:X65 + country + gamma, data=reg.data).
```

Also, a quick note, avoid using spaces as column names. Use `_` instead.

EDIT: Find correction between X1 and all other variables:

There probably is a much better approach but this should work:

I first make sure you have tibble, select the columns of interest to correlate against, apply the `cor` function, convert from matrix back to tibble and select the first row which is x1 against all other vars.

```
reg.data %>% 
  as_tibble() %>%
  select(X1:X5) %>% 
  cor() %>% 
  as_tibble %>% 
  slice(1)
```

Comment: Thanks, I realize there is an error in my thinking. Instead, if I wanted to just calculate the correlation of each variable relative to X1 using a for loop, order them from smallest to largest correlation, then graph them, how would you go about doing that?